# Passing parameters to Dapper Select query for Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, select, model-view-controller, dapper

I'm trying to pass parameters to Dapper for a select query in an Oracle database, but somehow, it doesn't work with the ":" identifier.

It works fine using string concatenation :
    `string req = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE code_comite = '";
        req += user.Comite + "' AND (pers_name LIKE '";
        req += name + "%' OR pers_surname LIKE '" + name + "%')";
 contacts = db_conn.Query<Contact>(req).ToList();`

But not with Dapper parameters passing :

```
string comite = "'" + user.Comite + "'";//e.g. comite = '120'
name = "'" + name + "%'";//e.g. name = 'John%'
contacts = db_conn.Query<Contact>("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE code_comite = :code_comite AND (pers_nom LIKE :search OR pers_prenom LIKE :search)", new { code_comite = comite, search = name }).ToList();
```

It should use the same string but the second example returns me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put quotes around your values when you pass a parameter. On the contrary this causes a fail because the engine will search a column containing your values surrounded by the literal quotes.
Just use the plain text

```
 string comite = user.Comite;
 name = name + "%";
 contacts = db_conn.Query<Contact>(@"SELECT * FROM contact 
          WHERE code_comite = :code_comite 
            AND (pers_nom LIKE :search 
                 OR pers_prenom LIKE :search)", 
  new { code_comite = comite, search = name }).ToList();
```